# Unable to set state in a react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that looks like this. I call a method cleanUpInvoices
to format a date in my array object(invoices). This works very well without any
problem. I tried to setState to dateCleanUpResult.
All I get is "dateCleanUpResult is not defined". I have tried so many things and nothing works.
I am not able to set state.

What is wrong with this code?

Here is the entire code

```
        class Tester extends PureComponent { 

            constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
              invoices:[],
              startDate:'',
              endDate:'',
              queryResult:[],
              dateCleanUpResult:[]
            };

            this.searchForInvoicesByDates = this.searchForInvoicesByDates.bind(this);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.cleanUpInvoices = this.cleanUpInvoices.bind(this);
          }

          handleChange({ target }) {
            this.setState({
              [target.name]: target.value
            });
          }

          componentDidMount() {
            const getCustomerId = this.props.customer.customerId;

            AXIOS_AUTHED.get(`${API}/customers/${getCustomerId}/invoices?sort=settledDate,desc`)
              .then(res => {
                const invoices= res.data.content;
                this.setState({ invoices });
              })   
          }

          cleanUpInvoices(){

            const invoice = this.state.invoices;
            invoice.forEach(function(invoicer) {
                        const newDate = invoicer.settledDate.substring(0, invoicer.settledDate.indexOf('T'));
                    invoicer.settledDate = moment(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                    });

                    return this.setState({
                      dateCleanUpResult: invoice
                    }, () => this.state.dateCleanUpResult);        

          }


          searchForInvoicesByDates(startDate, endDate){

            var myResult = this.cleanUpInvoices();
            console.log(myResult);

          //now perform your date search based on the result from above
          let cleanedStartDate =  moment(startDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
          let cleanedEndDate =   moment(endDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

          let filteredResult = [];

          for(let i = 0; i < this.state.dateCleanUpResult.length; i++){

            if(this.state.dateCleanUpResult[i].settledDate >= cleanedStartDate &&  this.state.dateCleanUpResult[i].settledDate <= cleanedEndDate) {
              filteredResult.push(this.state.dateCleanUpResult[i]);
             }
          }
          console.log(filteredResult);

          const listItems = filteredResult.map((number) =>
            <li key={number.orderNumber}>{number.orderNumber} - {moment(number.settledDate).format('MMM-DD-YYYY')} </li>
          );
          this.setState({queryResult:listItems});
          return (      
            <ul>{listItems}</ul>
          );


          }

          render() {
            return (
              <PageBase
                navigation={['Customer Solution', 'Tester App']}
              >
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <Paper>
                      <Typography className="customer-solution-subheader" component="h3" variant="subheading">
                        Tester App
                      </Typography>
                      <form>
                        <div className="customer-form-details">                     
                          <span>DATE RANGE COVERED*</span><br/>

                          <span className="ctrCalendar">
                            <label htmlFor="start">Start date:</label>
                            <input type="date" id="start" name="startDate" value={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChange} required></input>
                          </span>
                          <span className="ctrCalendar">      
                            <label htmlFor="start">End date:</label>
                            <input type="date" id="end" name="endDate" value={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.handleChange} required></input>
                          </span>
                          <span>
                          <Button variant="contained" className="next-button" id="btnSearchDates" onClick={() =>this.searchForInvoicesByDates(this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate)}>Search</Button><br/><br/>
                          </span>

                          <p>Search Result (Invoices/Dates)</p>
                          <div role="content" className="invContentParent">
                            <div name="teach" id="invContentChild">

                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </form>                           

                    </Paper>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </PageBase>
            );
          }
        }

        export default Tester;
```

Comment: I have run the exact code as you and don't get the error that you are getting. May be you can share the whole class component. If you think that `this.state.dateCleanUpResult` is not getting the correct result that is because setState is asynchronous. So you won't see your changes reflected in any immediate console log. Would love to solve the issue if you can share some more info,

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that because an array is a reference type, invoice is actually holding a ref and pointing to your array in state, which you are thereafter mutating. Perhaps try explicitly cloning the state array like const invoice = [...this.state.invoices]. I believe there is an issue beyond the asynchronous nature of setting state, as your are starting with an empty array, not undefined.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how I can past the whole code but its a lot of code

Comment: Just use the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/efp82rjg/3/ and share that with us.

Comment: I have added the entire component

Comment: I see that you are not using dateCleanUpResult in your jsx. So that means you don't need to make it part of state. Just create a class property called dateCleanUpResult and store the value in that and return that. Your issues are simply due to the fact that you expected this.cleanUpInvoices() to return updated values. Which it won't because setState is asynchronous.

Comment: As I suggested above, have you attempted to address the fact that your method is directly mutating a reference to the array in state? This alone can cause some odd behavior. You should first clone the array from state that you are mutating.

Comment: @Greg-I will also put that in mind and fix it

Comment: @GregBrodzik is right to mention that you should not mutate state. But rather than cloning that state element (because that will only shallow clone it) just loop over invoices and store the data in a new array instead of the invoicer variable like you have done so.

Comment: @HasanWajahat good pt, .map could work nicely

Comment: @user2320476 I have also proposed a workaround to the async issue in my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost right, but what's happining is that when you return the for the array it could be just the empty array you are initializing at the `state` of the component.

We fix that be passing a callback function to `setState` method, which is a function that returns the state you want, the updated one right?

That callback function will be invoked after insuring that the new `state` has been set, and, we also return the `setState` function, because it's the one that is returning the new state.

```
  return this.setState({
    dateCleanUpResult: invoice
  }, () => this.state.dateCleanUpResult);
```

That [ARTICLE](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3) is a good explanation for that matter.

Comment: Thanks the state is getting set with your solution now but all settledDate is coming back as "Invalid date". It does not show the real dates anymore.

Comment: @user2320476 can you create a fiddle? you can use mine above.

Comment: @user2320476 can you provide a screenshot in your Question Post by editing it for `console.log('settledDate: ', invoicer.settledDate)`, put it as the first line in the `forEach` loop at you function `cleanUpInvoices`

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle showing that you can update the state in your case.
http://jsfiddle.net/efp82rjg/3/

I think you are getting an issue because you are assuming cleanUpInvoices() will return the updated value of state. But it won't because setState is asynchronous and even though the value will be updated but it won't show the updated value to you. If you want to access the updated value after setState() then use the call back that is available to you after setState function. Please read the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  invoices: [
    { settledDate: 'no' },
    { settledDate: 'no' },
  ],
  dateCleanUpResult: [],
  };

  this.cleanUpInvoices = this.cleanUpInvoices.bind(this);
  }


 cleanUpInvoices() {
  const invoice = this.state.invoices;
  invoice.forEach((invoicer) => {
    invoicer.settledDate = 'testing';
  });

this.setState({
  dateCleanUpResult: invoice,
});

return this.state.dateCleanUpResult;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.cleanUpInvoices}>test</button>
      {this.state.dateCleanUpResult.map(item => (
        <div>{item.settledDate}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you receive the value of "undefined" where you are logging the returned value cleanUpInvoices in your searchForInvoicesByDateMethod. Although this is the result of the async nature of setState, implementing a setState callback will not remedy this issue (without more, it will merely let you access the updated state in the scope of that handler). If you want to stick to your current implementation, I would return a promise and async/await the returned promise value. This will delay execution of code in your searchForInvoicesByDates method when cleanUpInvoices is called.

```
cleanUpInvoices(){
  // Avoid directly mutating state and generating circular reference by creating new array with map
  const invoice = this.state.invoices.map(invoice => Object.assign({}, invoice));
  //.....
  //.....
  return new Promise((res) => {
          return this.setState({
            dateCleanUpResult: invoice
     }, () => res(this.state.dateCleanUpResult)));  
  }     
}

////////

async searchForInvoicesByDates(startDate, endDate){
  var myResult = await this.cleanUpInvoices();
  //....
}
```

Trying not to deviate from the question posed, here is another quick thought that might simplify the implementation. Looks like you're initially making an API call on componentDidMount to retrieve the full universe of invoices, then generating a subset by date based on user input. Is it necessary to maintain the generated subset in state? Each time invoices are searched for by date, it seems you want to use the full universe returned from the API as your filter starting point. If that's the case, you can just immediately return the result from cleanUpInvoices -- no need for a state update. This would be different, of course, if you needed the invoice subset for further reference or manipulation.